# Intellij doesn't see the generated class by MapStruct

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-test, mapstruct

When I use `MapStruct` in `spring-boot` it generates an `impl class` and I want to have access on that file to import in unit test but intellij doesn't see it

```
@SpringBootTest(classes={OrderMapperImpl.class})
```

and I got error

```
Can't find a symbol OrderMapperImpl
```

Comment: did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45275382/how-to-write-junit-test-for-mapstruct-abstract-mapper-injected-via-spring) related question.

Comment: yes and it doesn't work because of intellij doesn't recognize the OrderMapperImpl because it is a generated class

Comment: Add the generated class folder to project sources.

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: How does the the pom declaration look like and which IntelliJ version are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tell IntelliJ to pick up mapstructs generated classes as source files by right-clicking on the directory `target/generated-sources/annotations > Mark directory as... > Generated Sources Root`.

If you have configured another output path you need to choose that instead.

Comment: any way to do that via pom?

Comment: If IntelliJ's `Generated sources folders` setting is set to `Detect automatically` (which is the default), it will automatically mark those directories under `target/generated-sources` and beyond after re-importing a project. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-importing.html