# How to write JUnit 5 Test for mapstruct mapper via Eclipse and SpringBoot

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, mapstruct

Basically I just would like to test my mapper which should be auto generated by MapStruct.

I tried all annotations possible and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45275382/how-to-write-junit-test-for-mapstruct-abstract-mapper-injected-via-spring) seems to be the best solution in order to work with sprinboot and junit 5 although it still does not work in my eclipse, somehow it just shows an error as seen below saying `ProductMapperImpl cannot be resolved to a type` although it should be autogenerated trough @Mapper annotation.
For example I am also using Lombok Annotation and all these auto generated methods eclipse recognizes and works absolutely fine.

So what did I do wrong? Maybe there is another way to autowire mapper interface to test class so that it works? Maybe it is something with the generated-sources folders and just eclipse somehow not recognizing it?

[image: error in IDE]

**TestClass**

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBootTest(classes = { ProductMapperImpl.class })
class ProductMapperTest {

  @Autowired
  private ProductMapper productMapper;

  @BeforeAll
  public static void setup() {
    log.info("Testing mapper between product entity and product dto...");
  }

  @Test
  public void test() {
    String hello = "Hello";
    assertTrue("Hello".equals(hello));
  }

  @Test
  public void shouldMapProductToDto() {
    // given
    User user1 = new User("username_1", "1", Role.STORE);
    RetailStore store1 = new RetailStore(user1, "store", "1234", "store@example.org");
    Category cat1 = new Category("vegetables");
    Product entity = new Product(cat1, "cucumber", new BigDecimal(0.99), store1);
    // when
    System.out.println(entity);
    ProductDto dto = productMapper.productToProductDto(entity);
    // then
    assertNotNull(dto);
    assertEquals(dto.getCategoryName(), entity.getCategory().getCatName());
    assertEquals(dto.getName(), entity.getName());
    assertEquals(dto.getPrice(), entity.getPrice());
    assertEquals(dto.getProductId(), entity.getProductId());
    assertEquals(dto.getStoreId(), entity.getRetailStore().getStoreId());
  }

  @Test
  public void shouldMapDtoToProduct() {
    // given
    ProductDto dto = new ProductDto();
    dto.setCategoryName("vegetables");
    dto.setDescription("description");
    dto.setLimitations("limitations");
    dto.setName("cucumber");
    dto.setPrice(new BigDecimal(1.99));
    dto.setProductId(1L);
    dto.setRemainingStock(1);
    dto.setStoreId(1L);
    // when
    Product entity = productMapper.productDtoToProduct(dto);
    // then
    assertNotNull(entity);
    assertEquals(entity.getCategory().getCatName(), dto.getCategoryName());
    assertEquals(entity.getDescription(), dto.getDescription());
    assertEquals(entity.getLimitations(), dto.getLimitations());
    assertEquals(entity.getName(), dto.getName());
    assertEquals(entity.getPrice(), dto.getPrice());
    assertEquals(entity.getProductId(), dto.getProductId());
    assertEquals(entity.getRemainingStock(), dto.getRemainingStock());
    assertEquals(entity.getRetailStore().getStoreId(), dto.getStoreId());
    assertEquals(entity.getRetailStore().getStoreId(), dto.getStoreId());
  }

}
```

**MapperClass**

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface ProductMapper {

  /**
   * Map product entity instance to product Dto instance.
   *
   * @param product entity product
   * @return dto product
   */
  @Mappings({ @Mapping(source = "category.catName", target = "categoryName"),
      @Mapping(source = "retailStore.storeId", target = "storeId") })
  ProductDto productToProductDto(Product product);

  /**
   * Map product Dto instance to product entity instance.
   *
   * @param productDto dto product
   * @return entity product
   */
  @Mappings({ @Mapping(source = "categoryName", target = "category.catName"),
      @Mapping(source = "storeId", target = "retailStore.storeId") })
  Product productDtoToProduct(ProductDto productDto);

  /**
   * Update product with the latest values from a product DTO.
   *
   * @param productDto dto product
   * @param product    entity product
   */
  @Mappings({ @Mapping(source = "categoryName", target = "category.catName"),
      @Mapping(source = "storeId", target = "retailStore.storeId") })
  void updateModel(ProductDto productDto, @MappingTarget Product product);

  // aggregated root

  /**
   * Map list of product entities to list of product DTOs.
   *
   * @param products List of product entities
   * @return list of product dto`s
   */
  @Mappings({ @Mapping(source = "category.catName", target = "categoryName"),
      @Mapping(source = "retailStore.storeId", target = "storeId") })
  List<ProductDto> toProductDtos(List<Product> products);

}
```

**product dto**

```
@Data
public class ProductDto {
  private Long productId;
  private String name;
  private String categoryName;
  private Long storeId;
  private BigDecimal price;
  private byte[] picture;
  private String description;
  private String limitations;
  private Integer remainingStock;
}
```

**product entity**

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Product {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "product_id")
  private Long productId;

  // defines foreign key column category_id and indicates the owner of the
  // ManyToOne relationship
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
  private Category category;

  @Lob
  @Basic
  private byte[] picture;

  private String name;

  private BigDecimal price;

  // defines foreign key column store_id and indicates the owner of the ManyToOne
  // relationship
  @JsonBackReference(value = "product-store")
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "store_id")
  private RetailStore retailStore;

  private String description;

  private String limitations;

  @Column(name = "remaining_stock")
  private Integer remainingStock;

  /**
   * Constructor.
   */
  protected Product() {
  }

  /**
   * Constructor.
   *
   * @param category    category of the product
   * @param name        name of the product
   * @param price       price of the product
   * @param retailStore retail store selling this product
   */
  public Product(Category category, String name, BigDecimal price, RetailStore retailStore) {
    super();
    this.category = category;
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.retailStore = retailStore;
  }

  /**
   * Converting bigDecimal scale (number of digits to the right of the decimal
   * point) of price to 2.
   */
  @PrePersist
  @PreUpdate
  public void pricePrecisionConvertion() {
    this.price.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
  }
```

Comment: I am having the same problem

Answer (score -1):

`@SpringBootTest(classes = { ProductMapperImpl.class })`  *<- can you delete this*

```
 @Autowired
      private ProductMapperImpl productMapperImpl ;  *<- add this*
```

Comment: Tried it, but I still get the same error, now at the newly added Autowired ProductMapperImpl instance.