# How do I get an instance of my decorated Mapstruct mapper in a unit test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mapstruct

I want to test a Mapstruct mapper. The code below works if I make my test integrational and annotate it with `@SpringBootTest`. However, I want to make it a unit test instead. How do I get that decorated mapper in that case?

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
@DecoratedWith(CardMapperDecorator.class)
public interface CardMapper {
   // and so on
}
```

---

```
@Component
public abstract class CardMapperDecorator implements CardMapper {

    private CardMapper delegate;

    @Autowired
    public void setDelegate(CardMapper delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }
   
    // and so on 

}
```

---

```
// commented out to avoid bootstrapping the Spring context
//@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
//@SpringBootTest
//@ActiveProfiles("test")
class CardMapperTest {

    private final String CARD_NUMBER = "1111222233334444";
//    @Autowired
    private CardMapper cardMapper;
// ...
    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
// this leads to an NPE later since the delegate field is not initialized
        cardMapper = Mappers.getMapper(CardMapper.class);
```

If I follow the documentation's [advice](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/1.0/api/org/mapstruct/DecoratedWith.html), then I changed the code to this by adding a constructor:

```
//@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public abstract class CardMapperDecorator implements CardMapper {

    private final CardMapper delegate;

//    @Autowired
//    public void setDelegate(CardMapper delegate) {
//        this.delegate = delegate;
//    }
}
```

I get another exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: by.afinny.credit.mapper.decorator.CardMapperDecorator: method 'void <init>()' not found
    at by.afinny.credit.mapper.CardMapperImpl.<init>(CardMapperImpl.java:28)
    ... 82 more
```

Why do I need some `void <init>`?

Comment: @AnishB. no, sorry. It's not a public repository

Comment: Ok. No problem.

Comment: @AnishB. but then the `delegate` field is cannot be initialized, and I get an NPE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `default` component model for mapper.

Change to this `@Mapper(componentModel = "default")` and see if this works.

Comment: I was in the middle of writing my answer when you posted ))

Comment: However, what if I want to keep the `componentModel`, to keep it a Spring component *and* test it as a unit, without bootstrapping the Spring context?

Comment: @JoreJoh See this question -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45275382/how-to-write-junit-test-for-mapstruct-abstract-mapper-injected-via-spring

Answer (score 0):

Since I had the component model "spring" in my `pom.xml`, I had to override it in my `@Mapper` interface for this to work. Change this

```java
@Mapper
```

to this

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "default")
```

IntelliJ may say it's redundant to pass a default attribute value, but you should ignore it on that